# Add custom field to search_api_solr index

Tags: search

I've used [search_api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), [search_api_solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), [search_api_sorts](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_sorts), [search_api_sorts_widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_sorts_widget), [nodeviewcount](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) modules.

I have tried to add custom field into search_api_solr index which contains number of views for a node and also sort using this custom field.

How to do this?